# Change Server and Client Collation and Charsets in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to change my mysql server variables one by one (without using the my.cnf file). I need it to look like this

[image]

How can I change these variable names without editing the my.cnf?

**UPDATE**

This is what it looks like now.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a before/after? You show what you need it to look like, but what does it look like now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run update statements on the table?

```
UPDATE myTable SET value = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' WHERE variable_name = 'collation_connection';
```

And so on for the other necessary updates.

Comment: Yes I can but I need really need the client and server variables to be set to **utf8mb4_general_ci**.

Comment: I don't understand, aren't they already set to that value? Why do you need to change it then?

Comment: Ahh as a matter of fact your answer solved my problem. Thanks.